# Set a background color conditionally in Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: flash-builder, background-color

I am trying to set the background color of a mx:TabNavigator with the following line of code...

```
backgroundColor="{isDistrictFair == 'false'?'#EFF7F9':'#E9E3D2'}"
```

I am getting the following error...

> 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type uint.

Not sure which value the error refers to. isDistrictFair is a string var that contains either "true" or "false".

I got the 2 color values I wanted by setting the TabNavigator background while in Design mode which creates the following line of codes...

```
backgroundColor="#EFF7F9"
```

and..

```
backgroundColor="#E9E3D2"
```

So I thought I could get the background colors set conditionally, but can't figure out the proper syntax.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple - rather than using the string hash notation for the color, use the 0x prefix for an integer:

```
backgroundColor="{isDistricitFair == 'false' ? 0xEFF7F9 : 0xE9E3D2}"
```

Comment: Thanks Bill! I knew it had to be something simple.